# Firebase functions emulator requesting external network resource: computeMetadata

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have the firebase emulator running in a docker container locally for testing. The emulator includes everything I'm using for my app (firestore, auth, functions, storage) so that I can develop and test independently of the production environment.

However, I'm getting these warnings which are making me nervous:

```
functions: Beginning execution of "myFunction"
⚠  External network resource requested!
   - URL: "http://---.---.---.---/computeMetadata/v1/instance"
- Be careful, this may be a production service.
```

I don't know what that URL is? Does it mean I've misconfigured something somewhere?

---

I'm also getting these warnings:

```
⚠  emulators: You are not currently authenticated so some features may not work correctly. Please run firebase login to authenticate the CLI.
⚠  functions: You are not signed in to the Firebase CLI. If you have authorized this machine using gcloud application-default credentials those may be discovered and used to access production services.
⚠  functions: Unable to fetch project Admin SDK configuration, Admin SDK behavior in Cloud Functions emulator may be incorrect.
```

But I don't think I want to authenticate, right? I don't want to touch anything to do with the live project on production while testing locally. Can I safely ignore these, or is there a good reason to authenticate?

Comment: please let me know if my recommendations in the answer below were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are indicative that there had some issues while initialization during the setup for emulators .
Make sure that the emulator is installed by the following command: `firebase setup:emulators:firestore`, for this you can refer [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator).
Deploy your function in the firebase in order to get recognized. you can refer to the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#run_the_emulator_suite) using firebase deploy --only functions
Also to be sure please check your Firebase json and see if the local host is configured and not the production host,just to be sure.
For further reference you can follow up the stackoverflow thread  [Docker authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072300/firebase-authentication-emulator-ui-in-docker-container-doesnt-work-on-localhos)and [Firestore emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73261467/running-front-end-tests-with-firestore-emulator-inside-docker)where a similar issue has been raised by other users which might be helpful.